# Should I include hadoop-common or hadoop-core in my spark application

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to get a simple word count spark application running locally and reads file from remote hadoop cluster.

In the maven dependencies when added hadoop-core (last version 1.2.1) in my dependencies to get ride of this exception

`Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries`

Then I got another exception which is

`Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4`

so I included hadoop-common (last version 2.6.0) in my dependencies.

At this stage the first exception is thrown again.

What is the problem here? I believe there is a dependencies conflict but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Spark release built with the correct Hadoop version that you are using ?
you can get the pre-built versions from Apache Spark download page. Hope this helps..

http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html